# dollar sign inside eval string in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, eval

I have hundreds of sub-directories which contain a dollar sign (i.e., `$`) 
as the 1st character in their names, each of which needs to be visited. 
These sub-directories can not be renamed. The bash script function tries to visit each 
and (so far) to echo the path its in. Trying to do this via a built path string then eval it.

The line that print `cmd=${cmd}` indeed shows `cmd=cd /rbyoko/c/$Ono.RCB` as expected -
however, the eval command mis-interprets the `$Ono.RCB` (probably as `$Ono` being empty var)
and results in: `-bash: cd: /rbyoko/c/.BIN/: No such file or directory`
then the following line prints  `We are in  /home/user` (where the script was run from).

My question: how do I eval the string (and/or escape the sub-directory with `$`) to 
actually succeed in visiting the desired sub-directory?

Here is my function:

```
visit_tree_recbin()
{
            strings="cdhlotpw"
            MACHINE=`uname -a`
            PWD=`pwd`
            for i in $(seq 1 ${#strings})
            do
                c="${strings:i-1:1}"
                echo "Letter $i: $c"
                #build eval string to do: cd "/rbyoko/${c}/\$Ono.RCB/"
                x1="cd /rbyoko/${c}/"
                x2="\$"
                x3="Ono.RCB/"
                cmd="${x1}${x2}${x3}"
                echo "cmd=${cmd}"
                eval "${x1}${x2}${x3}"
                echo "We are in " `pwd`
            done
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't the assignment `x2="\$"`? Try `x2="\\$"` or `x2='\$'` if you want to preserve the literal value of the backslash

Comment: Yes, that's it....the x2="\\$" fixed the issue, thanks !

Comment: Note that `PWD` is a variable that _already_ contains the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't try run commands stored in variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946) (unless it's just a simple command name and/or path).  It is bound to fail in interesting ways unless you get the quoting right (which can be fiddly and lead to less robust code).

In your case, it would be enough with

```
cd "/rbyoko/$c/\$Ono.RCB"
```

i.e. quote the directory pathname (to allow for `$c` to have whitespaces) and then escape the `$`.

Alternatively:

```
cd "/rbyoko/$c"/'$Ono.RCB'
```

i.e. single quote the bit with the dollar sign to protect it from the shell.

Your function, modified:

```
visit_tree_recbin () {
    for dir in c d h l o t p w; do
            cd "/rbyoko/$dir"/'$Ono.RCB'
            printf 'We are now in %s\n' "$PWD"
    done
}
```

Alternatively,

```
visit_tree_recbin () {
    for dirpath in /rbyoko/[cdhlotpw]/'$Ono.RCB'/; do
            cd "$dirpath"
            printf 'We are now in %s\n' "$PWD"
    done
}
```

The difference is that the first variation will create directory pathnames and `cd` into these.  This may fail if the directory does not exist.

The second variation uses a filename globbing pattern that matches *existing* directories.  If the pattern matches anything, the `cd` will succeed (if you have permission to `cd` into the directory).

Note that `bash` maintains a `PWD` variable that contains the pathname of the current working directory, so there's no need to use `pwd` here.